# JQuery Sortable Containment Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple list of subcategories inside categories like so:

```
<ul class="list">
<li>Eyewear
<ul class="cont">
  <li>Andy Wolf</li>
  <li>Matsuda</li>
  <li>Dita</li>
  <li>Barton Perreira</li>
  <li>Theo</li>
</ul></li>

<li>Merchandise
<ul class="cont">
  <li>Tees</li>
  <li>Tanks</li>
</ul></li>

<li>Accessories</li>
</ul>
```

For this example, I want to be able to move "Andy Wolf" within its "cont" parent, but not outside of it. I did the following:

```
$("ul.list").sortable({
  containment: $(".cont"),
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",    
  items: "li",
  axis: 'y',
  revert: true,
  update: function(event, ui){
      //ajax call
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

But for some reason "Andy Wolf" can go outside of "cont" and become the same level as "Eyewear".

Here's a fiddle I made https://jsfiddle.net/2901gLxL/7/

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the list items in `$("ul.cont")` to be sortable, you should be targeting that container.

Try this:

```
$("ul.cont").sortable({
    containment: 'parent',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",    
    items: "li",
    axis: 'y',
    revert: true,
        update: function(event, ui){

        }
    }).disableSelection();
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/bbwswysq/)**

Comment: Talk about not seeing the forest through the trees! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTML mistake, look at your `<li>`'s around "Eyewear"

```
<li>Eyewear
<ul class="cont">
  <li>Andy Wolf</li>
  <li>Matsuda</li>
  <li>Dita</li>
  <li>Barton Perreira</li>
  <li>Theo</li>
</ul></li>    <-- this shouldn't be here!
```

Try this instead:

```
<li>Eyewear</li>
<ul class="cont">
  <li>Andy Wolf</li>
  ...
```